# A weighted count of Egyptian fraction representations

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, unit-fractions

*Previously [asked and bountied at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4479360/28111):*

Given a positive rational $q$, let
$$\mathsf{E}(q)=\left\{X\in[\mathbb{N}]^{\mathit{fin}}: q=\sum_{x\in X}{1\over x}\right\}$$
be the set of [Egyptian fraction representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) (without duplication!) of $q$. For example, $\mathsf{E}(1)$ contains both $\{1\}$ and $\{2,3,6\}$, as well as infinitely many other finite sets.

I'm interested in the function $$\mathscr{E}: q\mapsto \sum_{X\in \mathsf{E}(q)} \left( \prod_{x\in X}{1\over x}\right).$$ Intuitively, I'm trying to count the Egyptian fraction representations of $q$; of course this is infinite regardless of what $q$ is (since ${1\over n}={1\over n+1}+{1\over n^2+n}$), but I'm tweaking things to pay more attention to "short" representations with "small" denominators.

In general, $\mathscr{E}$'s behavior seems rather complicated. At one point I had an outline of an argument that $\mathscr{E}(q)$ is indeed finite for all $q$, but it fell apart. So my two questions are:

> **Question 1**: What is $\mathscr{E}(1)$?

Of course we can trivially work out some lower bounds, e.g. $\mathscr{E}(1)>{37\over 36}$, but I don't see a way to approach a good exact understanding.

> **Question 2**: Is $\mathscr{E}(q)$ finite for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$?

I'm more broadly interested in any information about $\mathscr{E}$, or indeed other ways to "count" Egyptian fraction representations. Most of the research I can find is about determining *individual* Egyptian fraction representations which are "optimal" in some sense (e.g. minimal length), which isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

*(The "analytic number theory" is a total guess on  my part - feel free to retag more appropriately!)*

Comment: Just curious: have you tried obtaining upper bounds for $\mathscr{E}(1)$ as well? Perhaps that helps gain some insight

Comment: Here is a master's thesis on the subject for $q=1$: https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/90573/Crawford_MB_T_2019.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y